# Uncaught ReferenceError: Component is not defined

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I keep getting this error and unsure why in console and app wont load
**Uncaught ReferenceError: Navbar is not defined**

App.js

```
 <template>
  <div id="app">
    <Navbar />
    <router-view/>
  </div>
</template>
 
<script>
import Navbar from '@/components/Navbar' 
export default {
  name: 'App',
   components: {
     Navbar
  }
}
</script>
 
<style>
</style>
```

my components folder is flat so no subfolder, app and main js are in the root of src folder

```
src
->components
-->Navbar.vue
-->Othercomponent.vue
main.js
App.vue
```

Comment: try to import with the vue extension ``import Navbar from '@/components/Navbar.vue'``

Comment: thanks tried that as well as ./components but no such luck

Comment: components name in template are kebab-cased, so you should use your compoent like: <navbar></navbar>. also do not use self-closing component tags.

Comment: thanks for that switching to 
`code
 <Navbar></Navbar>
`
does not help either :/

Comment: I don't see any obvious reason for that code to cause that error. Double check that it is definitely that file that's causing the problem. A couple of other observations. 1. That appears to be a `.vue` file but you refer to it as `App.js` and `App.hs` in the question. If the extension isn't `.vue` you should change it. 2. The folder structure in the question has `componets` spelt incorrectly. I assume that's spelt correctly on your file-system.

Comment: yeah those are just my bad spelling components is spelt right in the file tree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Navbar.vue I did not put quotes around the name being exported

```
export default {
    name: 'Navbar',
    data(){
    return{}

}
```